# Good synonyms for concurrence in a computer sciences context

Tags: synonyms, computing

I'm looking for some good synonyms for **concurrence** because I'm repeating a lot this word in a text within a computer sciences context.

The meaning of this word in my text is: the fact of two or more processes/events happening at the same time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think about the words *simultaneity*, *simultaneousness*, *synchronicity*?

I personally think that all derivative forms of *simultaneous* should do the job just fine because first of all it's the closest one in meaning and secondly it really is the only word that's completely synonymous with *concurrency*.

Alternatively, you could try using different phraseology altogether. What I mean by that exactly is that instead of alternating the words *concurrency* and, let's say, *simultaneity*, you could use phrases like *happening simultaneously*, *happening in sync*, *concurrent events*, *running in parallel*, *simultaneous computation*, et cetera. There really are lots of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that the two events [*coincide*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coincide):

> to happen at the same time

<sub>(Merriam Webster)</sub>

Its noun form, *coincidence*, has some extra connotation, that it's more or less *random* that the events happen simultaneously.

Another option is [*simultaneous*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simultaneous):

> existing or taking place at the same time <simultaneous events>

<sub>(Merriam Webster)</sub>

Comment: Coincide sounds more like a literature context, but simultaneous is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, you may be able to use *in parallel*.

However, *concurrency* and *parallelism* have [two slightly different meanings](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190719/the-difference-between-concurrent-and-parallel-execution).

When using a word like *concurrent* that has a very specific meaning in the computer science field, perhaps it is best **not** to use a synonym.

Comment: another good one, I will be aware about the different meanings that you said.